# Node Canvas throwing error when running project

Tags: node.js, canvas, apple-m1

Node Canvas is not working for me on m1

When I try to run my project I get this error message:

`Error: dlopen(.../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node, 0x0001): tried: '.../node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/usr/local/lib/canvas.node' (no such file), '/usr/lib/canvas.node' (no such file)`

Already did:

`brew install pkg-config cairo pango libpng jpeg giflib librsvg`

`xcode-select --install`

`npm i canvas`

With no errors

Not sure how to debug this as there are people with Node Canvas working on m1 laptops, please help.

Answer (score 13):

The most important thing is to make sure your Node executable has been compiled for Apple Silicon, meaning there's a pre-built binary for `darwin-arm64`. You can see which versions have which binaries here (the following page has the binaries for Node version 16.13.1): https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.13.1/.

Node v14 has no pre-built binaries for `darwin-arm64` (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/36161), because it can't be compiled natively to Apple Silicon.

I use `volta` (https://volta.sh/) to manage my Node versions, so if you install Node v16 with `volta install node@16` and then run `npm i canvas`, you should get a correctly compiled `canvas.node` file.

If that fails, go to `node_modules/canvas` and run `npm install --build-from-source`, which will compile the C++ addon and output the corect `canvas.node`.

You can check this by running:

```sh
file node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node
# outputs: node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64
```

If it says `arm64` at the end, then you're good to go. If it still says `x86_64`, then something went wrong.